# How to stop NSPanel from stealing input of another app

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I have an NSPanel. It's purpose is to sit on top of everything in all spaces and it does that just fine.

I don't want it to ever become firstResponder and take focus from another app.

I sub classed NSPanel like so

```
class SomePanelClass: NSPanel {
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool{
        return false
    }
}
```

When the window shows or I drag it around the app I was in still appears to have focus and it's name is in the menu but keystrokes do not register in that app until I click back into it's window.

Is there something else I can do to prevent my app and panel from stealing input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to override canBecomeKeyWindow on your Panel subclass to return NO.

```
- (BOOL) canBecomeKeyWindow {
  return NO;
}
```